# How can I wrap everything inside a specified XML element with a new node using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

So, considering this XML:

```
<root>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>qwerty</td>
        <td>1234 <p>lorem ipsum</p> 5678</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<root>
```

...how might I transform it to look like this?

```
<root>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><BLAH>asdf</BLAH></td>
        <td><BLAH>qwerty</BLAH></td>
        <td><BLAH>1234 <p>lorem ipsum</p> 5678</BLAH></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</root>
```

Every instance of  `<td>`  would then be containing the  `<BLAH>` element, and the contents of each  `<td>`  would then be within the new node.

---

...so far, I have this XSL which is wrapping each  `<td>`  element with the new node, but on the *outside* and not on the *inside*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table//td">
        <BLAH>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </BLAH>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...this is producing this ***undesired*** result:

```
<root>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <BLAH><td>asdf</td></BLAH>
      <BLAH><td>qwerty</td></BLAH>
      <BLAH><td>1234 <p>lorem ipsum</p> 5678</td></BLAH>
    </tr>
  </table>
</root>
```

tested at http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `<BLAH>` inside of the `xsl:copy`:

```
<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <BLAH>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </BLAH>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ha wow -- that's a lot easier than I thought, thanks DevNull!

Comment: @IanCampbell - You're very welcome. Be sure to check the edit I made right after I answered that will make sure any attributes of `<td>` stay with `<td>`.

Comment: Check -- and tested at http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php, with the desired results. Thanks again.

Comment: @IanCampbell - I had an extra `node()` in the first `xsl:apply-templates`.  This would definitely give you unwanted results. Should be good now though :-)

Comment: Thanks @DevNull. Er, actually I just tested it again, and noticed that it the contents are being doubled, for example from `<td>asdf</td>` to `<td>asdf<BLAH>asdf</BLAH></td>`. It seems as if the line `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` is causing this, and when removed it is working fine though.

Comment: @IanCampbell - Yeah that extra `node()` was causing the doubling. You can leave the `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` to retain any attributes in `<td>`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hey that's cool, now it is working fine. So what would be the difference in using both the `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
` and `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
` here, as opposed to @SeanB.Durkin's usage of just `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
` instead?

Comment: @IanCampbell - SeanB.Durkin's usage of `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>` inside the `xsl:copy` means that any attributes in `<td>` will be moved to `<BLAH>`. For example, `<td attr="test">foo</td>` would become `<td><BLAH attr="test">foo</BLAH></td>`.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks for explaining that! So, the attributes should be copied first, outside of the node transformation.

Comment: @IanCampbell - Yes although it's not doing a copy of the attributes...it's applying the templates of the attributes. This means that you could still override the processing of those attributes with another template. Since you don't have a template matching any `td` attributes, your identity template is the one doing the copying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="td">
        <xsl:copy>
            <BLAH>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </BLAH>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think that will end up moving any attributes of `<td>` to `<BLAH>`.

Comment: Thanks @Sean for the help. However, as DevNull has stated, any possible attributes of `<td>` will be renamed to `BLAH` with this transformation (DevNull's below example -- `<td attr="test">foo</td>` will become `<td><BLAH attr="test">foo</BLAH></td>`; tested at http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php).